# Show a specific label at 'featured' section instead of latest posts

Tags: html, blogger

I'm using a blogger template for my website and I'm trying to change the featured section, instead of showing the latest post I want to display a specific label.

I have no understanding of it, but I believe this is the section that "controls" the featured section of the blog:

```
<div class='ct-wrapper' id='featured-posts-section'>
    <div class='featured-post padding clearfix'>        
        <script type='text/javaScript'>
            document.write(&quot;&lt;script src=\&quot;/feeds/posts/default?max-results=&quot;+featured_numposts+&quot;&amp;orderby=published&amp;alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=sliderposts\&quot;&gt;&lt;\/script&gt;&quot;);
        </script>                                                                                                           
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for the support!

This is the website link: https://www.santaclarabookstore.com.br/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to change the Feed URL to point to the specific Label's feed whose posts you want to show in the featured section. Let us suppose, the label that you want to display is called **labelName**. Then the above code will change in this manner (only the bold part is changed) -

```
<script type='text/javaScript'>
document.write(&quot;&lt;script src=\&quot;/feeds/posts/default/-/labelName?max-results=&quot;+featured_numposts+&quot;&amp;orderby=published&amp;alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=sliderposts\&quot;&gt;&lt;\/script&gt;&quot;);
</script>
```